# Heroku router log parameter description

Tags: logging, heroku

Heroku router log has 10 parameters and descriptions are in **https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-router-log-format**. 
one of the parameter is service.It described like **amount of time in milliseconds spent proxying data between the backend web process and the client**.
Is service time is response time of the request or what it is? Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

No. Service is the amount of time spent within the Heroku Router.
That router sits between your app and an AWS ELB, and know how to route a request to the right dyno depending on the provided hostname.